# Remove items (and keys) from array with a value of 0

Tags: php, arrays, foreach

I am trying to remove items from my array to make a new array with only items in it that have a value greater than 0. I tried stuff with the foreach loop, looked it up on internet, but nothing worked.

Here is my array

```
$productarray = array(
  'a' => 6,
  'b' => 0,
  'c' => 2,
  'd' => 1,
  'e' => 3,
  'f' => 4,
);
```

expected output:

```
  'a' => 6,
  'c' => 2,
  'd' => 1,
  'e' => 3,
  'f' => 4,
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The simplest and shortest way to do that is using the [`array_filter`](https://www.php.net/array_filter) function:

```
$productarray = array(
  'a' => 6,
  'b' => 0,
  'c' => 2,
  'd' => 1,
  'e' => 3,
  'f' => 4,
);
$productarray = array_filter($productarray);
print_r($productarray);
```

outputs:

```
 Array ( [a] => 6 [c] => 2 [d] => 1 [e] => 3 [f] => 4 )
```

As you see, the key with a *`null` equivalent* value was removed.

As the [documentation](https://www.php.net/array_filter) says:

> If no callback is supplied, all entries of array equal to FALSE (see [converting to boolean](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.boolean.php#language.types.boolean.casting)) will be removed.

Comment: @DylanStrijker in a monodimentional array sure. For a multi-dimensional array let's try it.

Answer (score 1):

This should help you on your way:

```
foreach($productarray as $key => $value) {
    if($value == 0) {
        unset($productarray[$key]);
    }
}
```

output:

```
array(5) {
  ["a"]=>
  int(6)
  ["c"]=>
  int(2)
  ["d"]=>
  int(1)
  ["e"]=>
  int(3)
  ["f"]=>
  int(4)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Simply use [array_search()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-search.php) and [unset](https://www.php.net/unset) to achieve what you need, Try the following code,

```
<?php

$productarray = array(
  'a' => 6,
  'b' => 0,
  'c' => 2,
  'd' => 1,
  'e' => 3,
  'f' => 4,
);

if (($key = array_search(0, $productarray)) !== false) {
    unset($productarray[$key]);
}

?>
```

> Output

```
Array
(
    [a] => 6
    [c] => 2
    [d] => 1
    [e] => 3
    [f] => 4
)
```

[array_search()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-search.php) — Searches the array for a given value and returns the first corresponding key if successful.

[unset](https://www.php.net/unset) — Unset a given variable.